# Android - How to get just the date from date time?

Tags: javascript, android, json, api

## Solved

I have data Json that contains birth date, when i display it it contains the time also. Please help me how can i just display the date without the time...?

this is my code to get the birth date

.....

```js
userBirthDate.setText(response.body().getData().getBirth_of_date().toString());
```

.....

From the comments I get solved my problem, I add substring(0,10); thanx all... ^_^

Comment: can you share your json response?

Comment: What is the implementation of getBirth_of_date?

Comment: what is string value of `(response.body().getData().getBirth_of_date().toString()`?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed this is my Json response
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "_id": "5910690faafae31edb2777cb",
    "email": "bangkit@gmail.com",
    "display_name": "Bangkit TE",
    "image": "path/image",
    "gender": "Laki-laki",
    "birth_of_area": "Jakarta",
    "birth_of_date": "1995-02-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "address": "Bandung",
    "zip_code": 51324
  },
  "message": "OK"
}

Comment: @JeroenHeier String

Comment: @NitinPatel the String value is "1995-02-21T00:00:00.000Z"

Comment: just format it to a String without time part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below solution:

```
String bDataStr = response.body().getData().getBirth_of_date().toString();
String bDateStr = bDataStr.substring(0,10);
if(bDateStr!=null && !bDateStr.equals(""))
    userBirthDate.setText(bDateStr);
```

Comment: For stackoverflow's newbie, Don't forget upvote the perfect answer which works for you.

Comment: Yes i will, but i still have 1 reputation so i still can't vote... I will when i have enought reputation... ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I can see your response and I found this for date and time as mentioned below

```
"birth_of_date": "1995-02-21T00:00:00.000Z"
```

and by using below line of code you get the date and time string

```
String bDataStr = response.body().getData().getBirth_of_date().toString();
```

now next step you split the string bDataStr with the token "T" by using string split method. And takes it 0 index value from array that String.split() method returns. You will get the date part only then. Hope it helps.

Comment: yay, thanx to all of you, i used substring(0,10) and it works... ^_^

Comment: great!! happy coding